# Confusing results on who is define inside the modern team site's site admin

Tags: development, office-365, office-365-groups, modern-team-site

I created a new SharePoint modern team site using the admin username & I defined the test user as the group owner, as follow:-

[image]

now when I checked who is defined as site collection admin from the SharePoint admin centre, i got that the test user + the creator (admin) are defined as site collection admin through the office 365 group's owners, as follow:-

[image]

so this gives an indication that the related office 365 group will have the test user + admin as owner >> but when i checked who is defined as the owner of the related office 365 inside the office 365 group admin menu, I got that only the test user is defined as follow:-

[image]

so why i am getting 2 different results? why inside the SharePoint admin centre the creator of the site will be shown inside the site admin, while inside office 365 group admin it will not!?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be an answer, but I hope it will help. I was not able to replicate the same behavior.

Tests:

1. Create a standalone modern Team site
2. Create a group-enabled modern Team site

**Results**

In both cases, the creator of the site collections was not granted any permissions to the sites. The only account was that was granted permissions what the one I specified during the site creation process. This person was became the Site collection admin permissions. When I tried to access the sites I created, I've got an "access denied error":

[image]